# Error "No suitable driver found for " executing jar file

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jar

I'm working on a simple java project that perform the connection to a SQLServer DB.

My project works fine when I run it from eclipse or other IDE like IntelliJ, but i have a problem when I try to run it from a JAR file.

Here the Java Builth Path of my application (with JDBC library):

[image]

I did File -> Export -> Runnable Jar File:

[image]

but when I try to run test2.jar:

16:03:49.159 ERROR: No suitable driver found for

16:03:49.159 ERROR: 08001

where I'm wrong?

Comment: Jars are essentially zip files. You can open up your compiled jar to ensure that the driver was included within your jarfile (you'd be looking for the same contents you'd see in that `sqljdbc42.jar`). The driver needs to be loaded one way or another, either through classloading the separate jar or by including it in your own jarfile. You might benefit from "extract required libraries into generated JAR".

Comment: Hi. The sqljdbc42.jar is inside the generated JAR file. I've also tried "extract required libraries into generated JAR" and "Copy required ..."....I've always the same problem

Comment: The jarfile itself shouldn't really be inside your generated jar if you're going for bundling the driver. What did the "Extract into" option do for you? What was the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. What do you mean? My target is to give the jar to my collegues in order to execute it also on their pc. I need a single file

Comment: I'm saying the `sqljdbc42.jar` itself should not be inside your `test2.jar`, but rather the _contents_ of `sqljdbc42.jar` should be inside of `test2.jar`. The alternative is loading it with a `ClassLoader`.

Comment: "Package required libraries into generated JAR" bundles the .jar files of your libraries into your application's .jar file and requires a custom loader to make use of them. Have you explored the other two options?

Comment: Yes, both. The problem is always the same.

Comment: If I use the option "extract required libraries into generated JAR". I see that in the final jar there are the *.class file and not the sqljdbc42.jar. But I receive always the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

The Jar file didn't read the properties file where I put the DBConnection URL and credentials.

I fix my code using getResourceAsStream and now it works.